# Add suffix to according to number

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add suffix according to any number in EXCEL. For example 11'dir, 12'dir, 13'dur, 15'tir,1'dir. You can see many suffix and many number. How  can ı solve this problem according to possible different numbers?

Comment: What is the logic which maps numbers to suffixes. For example, why does `dir` go with 11 rather than `dur` or `tir`?

Comment: These are Turkish Language suffix. When we talk about english like "-nd,-rd,-st,-th".

Comment: What version of excel are you using?

Comment: Working on EXCEL 2016

Comment: For those who don't know Turkish, could you give a link to a resource which explains the rules?

Comment: Maybe complex topic for general. So ı tried to explain it last comment as u can see. For example "-nd,-rd,-st,-th". These are changeable expression as in english.

Comment: In VBA if `x =11` is a number `suffix = "'dir"` is a string then `x & suffix` adds the suffix to the number. You could perhaps set up a dictionary which implements the number to suffix map. Since you say the mapping is to complex for the question, it is impossible to say much more.

Comment: Previous posts on ordinal numbers: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+ordinal+numbers+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: So as ı understand there is a lot possible case also in Turkish language but ı will try thanks to helping.